# Четкость шрифтов в PhpStorm 2016

Tags: phpstorm, шрифты

Все шрифты в phpstorm выглядят не очень комфортно. В Sublime Text 3 этот же шрифт выглядит более сглаженным, приятным. Может есть какие то настройки в phpstorm. ОС стоит windows 7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Настройки есть. Можно поменять сам шрифт и тип сглаживания.

Comment: Шрифты менял, сглаживание ставил Grey, стало немного лучше, но все равно не то.